# SSH Tunnel through (2) two JumpHosts

Tags: ssh

My target is server D, and I have to jump through hosts B and C to reach it. Normally when I jump from A to C with B in the middle, I set up a tunnel with this command and connect to https://127.0.0.1:1234:

```
ssh -L 1234:TARGET_SERVERIP:443 JumpHostB
```

But how should I establish a tunnel to the Target Server when there are 2 JumpHosts between A and D?

A: My Laptop
B: JumpHost 1
C: JumpHost 2
D: Target Server

Comment: Did I format something wrong to get a -1 ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, [please edit your post to include additional context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/485163/edit). What have you tried and what errors are you encountering? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer OpenSSSH has -J ([ProxyJump](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J)) option, which is able to handle multiple jump hosts. On your laptop you can use: `ssh -J A,B D`, or add something like that to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host D
    ProxyJump A,B
```

And then just use: `ssh D`

Comment: I can't make the port forwarding work with this syntax when using it on `macOS`.  I wonder if that flavor were different from the *nix ones